# Angular2 E2E Protractor. Wait until element has class

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, web-deployment

I need find a way to wait with my e2e test (angular2 project) until the tested *element gets an specific css class*.

Is there any possible way without `browser.wait()` or `browser.sleep()`?

Comment: Provide a reason *why*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: you want to wait without using `browser.wait()`? Doesn't make sense... that's what it is for.  To wait on something.

Answer (score 7):

You've even used the word "wait" in the question, but asking to solve it without the built-in waiting functions. I don't see much sense in that.

We've solved something similar before and came up with a *custom wait function* which can be used as an Expected Condition with `browser.wait()`:

```
function waitForCssClass(elementFinder, desiredClass) {
    return function () {
        return elementFinder.getAttribute('class').then(function (classValue) {
            return classValue && classValue.indexOf(desiredClass) >= 0;
        });
    };
};

browser.wait(waitForCssClass($("#myid"), "desiredClass"), 5000);
```

Comment: Why not just use [expectedCondition](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions). Provide an ElementFinder with the class and wait for for example VisibilityOf. So no custom methods, but "plain" Protractor api

Comment: @wswebcreation right, I thought about that, but here I'm assuming we cannot modify the locator of an element we want to wait to have a class. For instance, the element might be located by xpath, or by name, or by repeater etc.

Comment: True, but you know the class, so something like `$('.className')` or with a scope like `$('.scope').$('.className')` can be used as the ElementFinder for the Expected Condition

Answer (score 0):

This function waits for a class to disappears from an element, given the element object (ElementFinder) and the CSS class you want to check for.

```js
    static async waitCssClassToDisappear(elem:ElementFinder, cssClass:string, timeout?: number) {
        await browser.wait(()=>{
            return elem.getAttribute('class').then((value) =>{
                return value.indexOf(cssClass) < 0;
            });
        }, timeout ? timeout : Utils.defaultTimeout, 'CSS class did not disappear within specified timeout');
    }
```